# How to make authentication with OAuth2 and React Native using REST API?

Tags: authentication, react-native, oauth, oauth-2.0

I want to make an app that needs authentication, I want to use Oauth2 and I have my own REST API.

I know this is very brief question so I'm not expecting direct answer.

If you have any links or articles for this it would be helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a library such as [react-native-app-auth](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth) will help you a lot. There's quite a lot of setup to do which is explained in their documentation. Feel free to update if you run into troubles using it.

Answer (score 1):

Go through this blog: https://medium.com/@alexmngn/the-essential-boilerplate-to-authenticate-users-on-your-react-native-app-f7a8e0e04a42

it is very easy to understand and shows basic authentication by OAuth2.

Comment: This does not explain OAuth2 flow, just a normal login one